# Grade 10 Quadratic equation

Tags: conic-sections, quadratics

This was on my year 10 maths test and I gave up with 40 mins to complete:

Basically you were given the coordinates:
y intercept : (0,10)
1 x intercept: (10,0)
and y value of the vertex: +15

Can someone help me form a quadratic equation from just those coordinates?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

We can write it as

$$y=a(x-b)^2+c$$

where $c$ is the $y$-value at the vertex, $c=15$. Now we can make it pass through $(0,10) $ and $(10,0)$ and this will determine $a$ and $b$.

We get two equations:

$$10=a(0-b)^2+15$$

and $$0=a(10-b)^2+15$$

We need to solve the system

$$\begin{align}ab^2+15&=10\\a(b^2-20b+100)+15&=0\end{align}$$

So $-20b+100=0$, i.e. $b=5$. Hence $a=15/25$.

Comment: I tried this on a CAS calculator, could you please show more? And the value of x at the vertex is unknown, I am still unsure how to find it. the curve doesn't pass through (10,0). Sorry could you please clarify these questions for me? Thanks